# How do I add a variable's number to another variable in batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file

So, I'm making a game with income (variable) and every turn the money variable goes up, as much as the income variable is for example:

```
set income=350
set /a "money=money+INCOME"
```

If I use the normal `%VARIABLENAME%` to call the variable it doesn't work and the money value stays the same. Please help!

Comment: Ah, the classic [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg/30284028#30284028). Add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the start of your script and change `%money%` to `!money!`.

Comment: Please answer using an answer, even if you are going to use a link.

Comment: Please specify your question, if you mean that it would be: `:LOOP........ set BLAHBLAH............. goto LOOP` it's not

Comment: Are you certain that `set /a "money=%money%+%income%"` doesn't work?  This works correctly on my machine.  Unless it's inside the parentheses of a `FOR ... DO (...)` loop.  Then it's the delayed expansion problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could be caused by [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

This alternate script should work for you:

```
@echo off

set money=20 

set income=30

set /a money+=%income% 

pause
```

Comment: The /a for setting values is unnecessary!

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with delayed expansion.

Comment: I'm saying OP's problem was caused by delayed expansion

Comment: But you don't say how to solve it; you just remove the circumstances that require it in the first place, which won't address the actual problem.

Comment: I included a link about delayed expansion, then offered an alternate solution

Comment: Unlike `set /a money+=%income%`, the `set /a "money+=income"` works whether _delayed expansion_ is disabled or enabled. And BTW: it means take the value of `income` and add it to `money` variable and keeps `income` unchanged: the same as `set /a "money=money+income"`.

Comment: Doing math (4*4, 6/2, etc.) requires a `set /a "MATHHERE"`